# gradient descendent coust increass by each iteraction in linear regression with one feature

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, machine-learning

Hi I am learning some machine learning algorithms and for the sake of understanding I was trying to implement a linear regression algorithm with one feature using as cost function the Residual sum of squares for gradient descent  method as bellow:

**My pseudocode:**

```
 while not converge
     w <- w - step*gradient
```

python code 
Linear.py

```
import math
import numpy as num

def get_regression_predictions(input_feature, intercept, slope):
    predicted_output = [intercept + xi*slope for xi in input_feature]
    return(predicted_output)

def rss(input_feature, output, intercept,slope):
    return sum( [ ( output.iloc[i] - (intercept + slope*input_feature.iloc[i]) )**2 for i in range(len(output))])

def train(input_feature,output,intercept,slope):


    file = open("train.csv","w")
    file.write("ID,intercept,slope,RSS\n")
    i =0

    while True:

        print("RSS:",rss(input_feature, output, intercept,slope))
 file.write(str(i)+","+str(intercept)+","+str(slope)+","+str(rss(input_feature, output, intercept,slope))+"\n")
        i+=1

        gradient = [derivative(input_feature, output, intercept,slope,n) for n in range(0,2) ]

        step = 0.05
        intercept -= step*gradient[0]
        slope-= step*gradient[1]
    return intercept,slope 


 def derivative(input_feature, output, intercept,slope,n):
     if n==0:
         return sum( [ -2*(output.iloc[i] - (intercept + slope*input_feature.iloc[i])) for i in range(0,len(output))] ) 
     return sum( [  -2*(output.iloc[i] - (intercept + slope*input_feature.iloc[i]))*input_feature.iloc[i]  for i in range(0,len(output))] )
```

**With the main program:**

```
import Linear as lin
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split




df = pd.read_csv("test2.csv")


train = df

lin.train(train["X"],train["Y"], 0, 0)
```

The test2.csv:

```
X,Y
0,1
1,3
2,7
3,13
4,21
```

I resisted the value of rss on a file and noticed that the value of rss became worst at each iteration as follows:

```
ID,intercept,slope,RSS
0,0,0,669
1,4.5,14.0,3585.25
2,-7.25,-18.5,19714.3125
3,19.375,58.25,108855.953125
```

Mathematically I think it doesn't make any sense I review my own code many times I think it is correct, I am doing something else wrong?

Comment: Without actually going through your code, have you tried modifying your step size? It can also help to check your gradient descent method by applying it on a model that's really easy to check; e.g. try it on `f(x) = x^2` or something else super basic first.

Comment: Thanks, you are right apparently I misunderstood the impact of the step size on the algorithm, I also thank you for your recommendation of testing in a easy model

Comment: Did changing the step size solve your problem completely? If so, I can add it as an answer, but if not update your question with more specifics (with the results of these trials) and I might be able to dig through a bit more.

Comment: my problem was that I was not understanding why my cost functions was getting worst after each iteration, and my misunderstood of step was the cause of that. You can add that as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your cost isn't decreasing, that's usually a sign you're overshooting with your gradient descent approach, meaning too large of a step size.

[image: Large step size]

A smaller step size can help. You can also look into methods for variable step sizes, which can change each iteration to get you nice convergence properties and speed; usually, these methods change the step size with some proportionality to the gradient. Of course, the specifics depend on each problem.